# I realise OS specific browser testing is necessary but what about the specific OS's version?

Tags: css, html, cross-browser

I've been testing a website I design on my mac and also on windows. To be more specific mac osx snow leopard and windows 7.

Now I'm wondering if I will need to test further e.g. mac osx leopard, tiger ... windows xp, windows vista?

I've been wondering since I started all this browser testing stuff.

Kind regards

Comment: Of course. It's always a good idea to test across as many OSs and browsers as you can. That's why God created virtualization.

Comment: Browsers work pretty much independently of the OS. Some browser versions are locked to specific OS version windows, but if you can run the browser, it should work uniformly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only browser that's an issue IMO is IE as running multiple versions takes some setup and is not completely decoupled from the OS. The Developer Tools in IE 8/9/10 let you choose the rendering mode of earlier versions, but there are sometimes differences in the rendering between the simulated and "native" browser. Users of the other browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari) tend to upgrade quickly and in addition, even early versions of those browsers were fairly compliant (aside from CSS3 capabilities that were codified after they were released, but those usually degrade gracefully)

Great article in [Smashing Magazine about setting up testing for IE](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/02/reliable-cross-browser-testing-part-1-internet-explorer/) using virtual machines.

Comment: i've been using spoon.net, windows 7, mac osx for my browser testing and my website is fine in firefox from version 3 upwards but I'll only support 3.6 upwards. All opera's are fine, all safari fine,Chrome from version 13 upwards and finally IE from 7 upwards. 6 looks ok just a few tweaks needed but the images with transparent backgrounds show up weird. Seeing as my site is showing up fine in most browsers I'm wondering if it would be the same with the same tests but on XP or vista rather than windows 7.

Comment: @LondonGuy I rarely have to support IE6 anymore, but IE Collection handles that need when I do. I keep an XP SP3 Virtual Machine around just for IE7. Looking forward to that one falling off the list too ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Fonts are dependent on if the user's OS has them installed by default. Fonts have kerning (space between the characters), and if changed to a backup font with different kerning can affect the flow of your page.

Form elements (text inputs, radio buttons, dropdowns, etc.) are rendered by the browser but adhere to the OS standard settings.

In short, it's always good to get your hands on as many environments (OS/browser combinations) as possible to see what your site will look like. If you have a friend with a different set up, check it out, ask them to send you a screenshot or use one of the online services that provide this ability.

Comment: I could always set up some more parallels vm's one with xp and one with vista and repeat the same test I done on windows 7 but i'm wondering if it would be worth it. Would for example ie7 render my website different on xp from how it would on windows 7? I understand different OS's render quite differently but didn't think OS's version would matter when comparing windows 7, xp and vista. The problem I had with mac and windows was certain fonts weren't available so I redesigned my website with different fonts. Helvetica for mac and arial for windows.

Comment: you should design it in a way that slight changes in font wont affect your layout, or better yet use Google fonts. I generally don't test on different windows versions, but if you're serious and professional about it, it's something to think about.