# Why display "inline" works differently in Mac and Windows

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a complex HTML structure, and for align all HTML content. I apply CSS `display:inline` on an anchor tag; but it's not showing similarly on Chrome in Mac and Windows. When the site runs on the same browser on different OSes (Mac, Windows), the behaviour of the HTML is not the same.

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <span style="display: inline-block;">
            <a class="ReqFeedbackLink glyphicons list feedbackscloud" title="Submitted on: Dec 01 12:04 PM" style="padding-left: 20px; height: 18px; line-height: 18px; color: black;">Employee Handbook Acknowledgement (Rev. 4/6/2015) - Addendum 1
                <span style="color: Gray;">(Report: 330)</span>
                <span style="color: Gray; height: 18px; line-height: 18px; vertical-align: bottom;" title="Submitted on: Dec 01 12:04 PM"> signed by Bill Millington</span>
            </a>
            <span style="display: inline-block;" class="Feedbackicons">
                <a class="glyphicons pencil cloudPdpItems" style="margin-left: 7px;" title="Edit this document">&nbsp;</a>
            </span>
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Is there any way to achieve same behaviour on different-different operating system?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot showing the differences between the two?

Comment: Questions asking "why isn't this code working?" must include a specific explanation of what isn't working. "It doesn't look similar" isn't enough detail for us to go on.

Comment: @PraveenKumar please don't edit a post just to change spaces from 4 to 2.

Comment: @TylerH When it is 4 it is hard to read. That's why changed. But why not?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Because it's a stylistic and non-substantive change that meta has said "don't bother with", because for some people, only 2 spaces is hard to read.

Comment: Okay done! @TylerH. `:)`

Comment: Are both versions of Chrome the same?

Comment: i doubt different versions of chrome would make a difference they wouldn't change the engine with a regular software update

Comment: Just for testing, impose `!important` to your inline style. If the behaviour changes, it has to do with browser default styles implementation. Still no clue on why they would differ. @QuestionMarks My bad, missed it.

Comment: @Pamblam I doubt it too. I also doubt the OS has anything to do with the browser. Something else is probably at work here.

Comment: why wouldn't the os make a difference? everything sits on top of the os after all..

Comment: At least for me the snippet looks exactly the same on Windows and OS X.

Comment: re: os's - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855630/how-much-of-an-effect-can-different-operating-systems-have-on-displaying-web-pag

Answer (score 1):

This is completely normal. This is why developers use [resetter stylesheets](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjY4ora7YPKAhUE1CYKHSzZBlEQFggjMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F11578819%2Fcss-reset-what-exactly-does-it-do&usg=AFQjCNFkz65z1cweqJV_8_lYxz33RP2Yjw&sig2=2Q_sLyyYA59fFJKDGTJoHg) that make everything start from scratch. and puts all browsers on the same level. Start with one of those and then build the rest of your page on top of it.